# How do I implement smooth scrolling with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I've been struggling for two hours with several different jQuery plugins trying to get smooth scroll to work for my site.

Here is the relevant code right now:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
 <header class="span12 hero-unit">
 <ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="span3"></li>
  <li class="span2">
   <a href="#Blog" class="thumbnail">
   <img src="images/nav_icon-01.png" alt="Blog"/>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="span2">
   <a href="#Projects" class="thumbnail">
   <img src="images/nav_icon-02.png" alt="Projects"/>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="span2">
   <a href="#Contact" class="thumbnail">
   <img src="images/nav_icon-03.png" alt="Contact"/>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="span3"></li>

 </ul>
 </header>
</div>
```

I've deleted all my JS code (because I know that I wasn't using any of them correctly and would like to just start fresh) except this one, because this seems to actually work, but only activate upon page load and I want to know if it's possible to make it work upon click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $("#Blog").offset().top
}, 2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this plugin, but based on what works, something like (assuming a recent JQuery) :

```
$('a.thumbnail').on('click', function() {
  var to = $(this).attr('href'); // $(this) is the clicked link. We store its href.
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(to).offset().top }, 2000);
)};
```

If your JQuery is < 1.7, you can try .click(), which will work regardless of JQuery version :

```
$('a.thumbnail').click(function() {
  var to = $(this).attr('href');
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(to).offset().top }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I put it in at the end of the body with <script></script>, was that the right way to implement it? It's still not working, sorry for the silly questions.

Comment: Is your JQuery version recent ? .on() was introduced in 1.7. If it's not, you could use .live instead. You should put the script in document ready (http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Hi, now I have this
`<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a.thumbnail').on('click', function() {

  var to = $(this).attr('href'); // $(this) is the clicked link. We store its href.

  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(to).offset().top }, 2000);

)};
});
</script>`

I'm not sure if my jQuery is recent, how would I check that?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Should I have something in my header/how do I call on the jQuery?

Comment: It looks like your last bit of code has the brackets in the wrong order, which would cause this code not to work properly. ")};" should actually be "});".

Answer (score 1):

What mddw mentioned works, except that it will cause a rather big flicker unless you prevent the browser's default action as follows (also, his ending braces were in the wrong order):

```
$('a.thumbnail').on('click', function(event) {
  var to = $(this).attr('href');
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(to).offset().top }, 500);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```